# How to create table order by index in informix

Tags: informix

How I can table which is index order in informix ? This means when I insert new element it first order and then insert this element. In oracle I can do something like this:

```
ORGANIZATION INDEX
```

is there some equivalent in informix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no similar resource at Informix.

The option you have is reorder the physical rows based on one index from time to time by setting it to `cluster` with the `alter index` [statement](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0268.htm?lang=en).  (Setting an index to NOT CLUSTER is always very quick.)

But there some limitations in using it. The main limitation, in my opinion is:

- cannot be done online; this means, you need exclusive access during the operation.
  If the table is big, could take a while.

Quote the source: [IBM® Informix® 12.10 Index-type options](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0402.htm?lang=en)

> CLUSTER option usage
>
> You cannot specify the CLUSTER option and the ONLINE keyword in the
>   same statement. In addition, some secondary-access methods (such as
>   R-tree) do not support clustering. Before you specify CLUSTER for your
>   index, be sure that the index uses an access method that supports
>   clustering. The CREATE CLUSTER INDEX statement fails if a CLUSTER
>   index already exists on the same table.
>
> CREATE CLUSTER INDEX c_clust_ix ON customer (zipcode);
>
> This statement creates an index on the customer table and physically
>   orders the rows according to their postal code values, in (by default)
>   ascending order.
>
> If the CLUSTER option is specified and fragments exist on the data,
>   values are clustered only within each fragment, and not globally
>   across the entire table. If the CREATE CLUSTER INDEX statement also
>   includes the COMPRESSED keyword as a storage option, the database
>   server issues error -26950. To create a cluster index that supports
>   compression requires two steps:
>
> Use the CREATE CLUSTER INDEX statement to define a cluster index with no index compression.
>       Call the SQL administration API task( ) or admin( ) function with the 'index compress' argument to compress the existing cluster index.
>
> You cannot use the CLUSTER option on a forest of trees index.

Comment: hm this is sad. I cant execute this in runtime because there is still some traffic and my table is really big. This is the reason why I am ordering element during inserting to keep selecting more effective

Comment: If you want, you can request the use of IBM this site: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/ of course depends on the approval and this is influenced by your technical needs, business justification.